# UserControl passes click event to MainWindow Twice

Tags: wpf, vb.net, events, user-controls

I have finally gotten my UserControl to do everything I need, generating a button with an icon and text, but when I try to pass the click event up to my Main Window, I find it fires twice! In the abbreviated code below, my test MessageBox comes up twice in response to a single click. That is, it comes up once. I click OK and it comes up a second time. After I click OK the second time it continues. Thank you for looking this over.

```
<UserControl x:Class=ImageButton"
....
<Button Style="{DynamicResource ImageButtonStyle}" Click="uc_Click"/>
</UserControl>
----
Public Class ImageButton
Public Event Click as RoutedEventHandler
....
Private Sub uc_Click(sender as Object, e As RoutedEventArgs)
    RaiseEvent Click(Me, e)
End Sub
End Class
----
<Window x:Class="MainWindow"
....
<local:ImageButton x:Name=NewItem" Click="NI_Click"></local:ImageButton>
----
Class MainWindow
....
 Private Sub NI_Click(sender As Object, e As RoutedEventArgs) Handles NewItem.Click
    MessageBox.Show("Success")
End Sub
End Class
```

Comment: post complete usercontrol code

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You add two event handlers in the XAML and in the code-behind.

Just remove `Handles NewItem.Click` from `MainWindow` class code behind:

```
Private Sub NI_Click(sender As Object, e As RoutedEventArgs)
    MessageBox.Show("Success")
End Sub
```

**Or** remove `Click="NI_Click"` from view:

```
...
<local:ImageButton x:Name="NewItem"></local:ImageButton>
...
```

Comment: Thank you. That solved the problem. Didn't realize each created a different handler. Thank you!